# How to create tls ca when register and enroll new peer by Fabric CA client for Hyperledger Fabricv1.0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have no idea about "How to create tls ca when register and enroll new peer by Fabric CA client for Hyperledger Fabricv1.0"

```
1. I start up a 2 org 4 peers and 2 ca network
2. Enroll admin at CA, register new peer2 for org1, then get peer2's cacerts, keystore and signcerts
3. Ctrl-c the network, edit docker-compose.yaml to add peer2 in org1
4. Put the peer2's cacerts, keystore and signcerts in the crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer2.org1.example.com/msp folder
5. I have no idea how to create tls ca, so I just copy crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls folder to crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer2.org1.example.com
6. Besides, I also copy admincerts & tlscacerts folder from peer0 to peer2
7. Start network with peer2.org1.example.com and other peers successfully.
8. Try to join peer2.org1.example.com into existing mychannel but fail like bellow

root@4a3c71ab678b:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel
root@4a3c71ab678b:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer2.org1.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer channel join -b mychannel.block
2017-09-20 07:14:11.786 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2017-09-20 07:14:11.786 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
Error: Error getting endorser client channel: PER:404 - Error trying to connect to local peer
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/common/common.go:116 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/common.GetEndorserClient
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel/channel.go:149 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel.InitCmdFactory
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel/join.go:138 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel.join
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel/join.go:42 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel.joinCmd.func1
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:599 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:689 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:648 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/main.go:118 main.main
/opt/go/src/runtime/proc.go:192 runtime.main
/opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2087 runtime.goexit
Caused by: x509: certificate is valid for peer0.org1.example.com, peer0, not peer2.org1.example.com
```

many thanks for advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That failure means the server's TLS certificate referred to by the CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE is for another server with a different hostname.

The following shows how to use the fabric-ca-client to get your TLS certificate and key for a peer.

```
# To enroll the peer to get a TLS cert:
fabric-ca-client enroll -d --enrollment.profile tls -u $ENROLLMENT_URL -M /tmp/tls --csr.hosts $PEER_HOST

# Copy the TLS key and cert to the appropriate place
TLSDIR=$PEER_HOME/tls
mkdir -p $TLSDIR
cp /tmp/tls/signcerts/* $CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE
cp /tmp/tls/keystore/* $CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE
rm -rf /tmp/tls`
```

By the way, there is a complete sample which does this and more but is not yet merged.

Here is the change set for the sample which is in the hyperledger/fabric-samples repository:

- https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/#/c/13213/  (see the README.md)

In order to run this sample currently, you would also need these two change sets:

- For the hyperledger/fabric repository: https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/#/c/13265/
- For the hyperledger/fabric-ca repository: https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/#/c/13195/